# Display only results with matching IDs from Array?

Tags: php, joomla

EDIT: **ISSUE has been SOLVED**

I had to use "loadColumn" for the first query, and change the "array" to $results. That is literally all! So glad it's working now. Thanks for all the answers :) I will post the updated code at the bottom of the page.

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I want to display some values from my database based on a Status field which has the value "Pending". Let's say I submit a form on my website. It has a "SubmissionId" of "50". So multiple values such as "Container1", "Status1", "Date1", "BayanNo1" can all have the SAME SubmissionId.

Here is the code I have written, but it is not loading when I run the page:

```
<?php 

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $db->getQuery(true);

    $db->setQuery("SELECT `SubmissionId` FROM `jos_rsform_submission_values` WHERE `FieldName` = \"Status1\" AND `FieldValue` = \"Pending\"");
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();

    //First query which gets the SubmissionId where "Status" is "Pending"
    //Trying to add these SubmissionId's into an array (don't know if correct or not)
    $arr = [$results];

    //Second query which must display the ContainerNumber based on SubmissionId (Some values are from the same form that the user submitted, that is why the Status and ContainerNumber have the same SubmissionId

    $db->getQuery(true);
    $db->setQuery("SELECT `SubmissionId`, `FieldValue` FROM `jos_rsform_submission_values` WHERE `FieldName` = \"Container1\" AND `SubmissionId` IN '" .$arr. "' "); 

    $result = $db->loadObjectList();

    foreach($result as $value) {
        foreach($value as $key => $data) { 
          echo $data."<br />"; 
       }
   }
?>
```

**Here is the updated and working code:**

```
<?php 

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $db->getQuery(true);

    $db->setQuery("SELECT `SubmissionId`, `FieldValue` FROM `jos_rsform_submission_values` WHERE `FieldName` = \"Status1\" AND `FieldValue` = \"Pending\"");

    $results = $db->loadColumn();

    //First query which gets the SubmissionId where "Status" is "Pending"

    //Second query which must display the ContainerNumber based on SubmissionId 

    $db->getQuery(true);
    $db->setQuery("SELECT `FieldValue` FROM `jos_rsform_submission_values` WHERE `FieldName` = \"Container1\" AND `SubmissionId` IN ('".implode("', '", $results)."') ORDER BY `jos_rsform_submission_values`.`SubmissionId`"); 

    $result = $db->loadObjectList();
    foreach($result as $value) {
        foreach($value as $key => $data) { 
          echo $data."<br />"; 
       }
   }
?>
```

Comment: you have tried print_r($result) or try debuging all arrays

Comment: I have not tried print_r($result) but I will do so now.

Comment: It is giving me a value when I print_($result) or $arr.

Comment: now you checked this returns only matched value or not

Comment: The second print_r($result) is only giving me the value "Array ()" ; while the print_r($arr) is giving me the correct values. There must be something wrong with the second query

Comment: I have edit your code please check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169572/discussion-between-anand-choudhary-and-mailblade).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for IN in SQL is: `select * from foo where bar in ('1','2', '3')`

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->getQuery(true);

$db->setQuery("SELECT `SubmissionId` FROM `jos_rsform_submission_values` WHERE `FieldName` = \"Status1\" AND `FieldValue` = \"Pending\"");
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

//First query which gets the SubmissionId where "Status" is "Pending"
//Trying to add these SubmissionId's into an array (don't know if correct or not)

$arr = array_map($db->quote, $results));
//Second query which must display the ContainerNumber based on SubmissionId (Some values are from the same form that the user submitted, that is why the Status and ContainerNumber have the same SubmissionId

$db->getQuery(true);
$db->setQuery("SELECT `SubmissionId`, `FieldValue` FROM `jos_rsform_submission_values` WHERE `FieldName` = \"Container1\" AND `SubmissionId` IN (" .implode(',', $arr). ") "); 

$result = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach($result as $value) {
    foreach($value as $key => $data) { 
      echo $data."<br />"; 
   }
}
```

The code quotes your array with array_map and uses it in an IN expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `in_array()` in `php` .I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Where do you want me to add the "in_array"

Comment: `foreach($result as $value) {` In this loop you can use `in_array()`.